# Sass conditional input mixin

Tags: css, sass

So, I want to create a conditional sass class that takes in an argument and creates a class based on that argument.  I'm not even sure what this would be called.  Example:

```
<img class="width-200" .../>
```

where I'd create some kind of sass mixin that would take in the value after the '-' and then spit out a width: [input] + 'px;'.

Is there anything like that in SASS? What would I even call that to ask the right question?

Comment: There is.  It's where you use loops to build out the classes, but it's very inefficient.  Can you narrow down your range to something like `width-200`, `width-400`, `width-800`, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly then I think this is what you are looking for. You can create a simple mixin to create a class or attribute based on a variable and as mentioned in the comments you can loop over a map to create a range of classes.

```
// mixin that outputs a class
@mixin width-class($width) {
  .width-#{$width} {
    width: #{$width}px;  
  }
};

@include width-class(234);
// .width-234 {
//    width: 234px;
// }


// mixin that outputs an attribute
@mixin width-attr($width) {
    width: #{$width}px;
};

div {
  @include width-attr(567);  
}
// div {
//   width: 567px;
// }


// Loop using a mixin with a map to create classes
$width-map: (
  100,
  200,
  300,
  400
);

@each $width in $width-map {
  @include width-class($width);
}
// .width-100 {
//   width: 100px;
// }
// .width-200 {
//   width: 200px;
// }
// .width-300 {
//   width: 300px;
// }
// .width-400 {
//   width: 400px;
// }
```